# different rspec results when using spork

Tags: rspec-rails, spork

I have recently added Spork to my development stack and am just loving the increased speed but there are a few tests which perform differently with or without spork.

The test in question is pretty simple, it tests that one class of object can take two other objects and create a join between them.

```
it 'should associate object1 with object2' do 
  @object_under_test.action_being_tested(object1, object2)   #action
  object1.associated_objects.should be_include(object2)      #assertion
end
```

If I run this test **with** spork running then this test passes fine.  However **without** spork the assertion fails.  I can make it pass with or without spork by reloading `object1` before making the assertion.

```
it 'should associate object1 with object2' do 
  @object_under_test.action_being_tested(object1, object2)   #action
  object1.reload
  object1.associated_objects.should be_include(object2)      #assertion
end
```

From the point of intended behavior needing to add the `reload` in these tests is not really a problem as `object1` would get reloaded anyway before any calls to its' `associated_objects` are made.
I just think it odd that the two ways of running the tests have different results.  I get the feeling that I'm missing some core bit of knowledge about how spork works!  Like, does spork automatically reload objects?
If anyone can shed some light on this for me I'd be really grateful.